# How to check assertion error in Mocha when testing async code

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

When testing async code with Mocha and one of my asserts fails, all Mocha does is to report a timeout error. Is there a way to improve this? How to know what asserts failed and why?

```
mocha

  Contact
    #getContacts()
      1) should return at least 1 contact


  0 passing (3s)
  1 failing

  1) Contact #getContacts() should return at least 1 contact:
     Error: timeout of 3000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Code:

```
var assert         = require("assert");
var contact        = require("../lib/contact.js");
var chai           = require('chai');
var should         = chai.should();

describe('Contact', function() {
  describe('#getContacts()', function() {
    it('should return at least 1 contact', function(done) {
      contact.getContacts().then(function(contacts) {
        assert.equal(4,2)

        done()
      });
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Try to set a higher timeout for this specific test with a `this.setTimeout(10000)`, just to make sure it's not just a matter of how long your `getContacts()` is taking to finish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the assertion fails, which throws an exception. This causes the promise to be rejected, but there isn't anyone to notice. Your code only checks if the promise succeeds. If you return the promise, then mocha will check for it and fail the test if the promise is rejected.

So you want

```
it('should return at least 1 contact', function() {
    return contact.getContacts().then(function(contacts) {
      assert.equal(4,2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return the promise like this:

```
it('should return at least 1 contact', function() {
  return contact.getContacts().then(function(contacts) {
    assert.equal(4,2);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like when the assert throws an error that error is swallowed and never shown and also the code after assert throws is skipped.

Try like this (catching the reject):

```
it('should return at least 1 contact', function(done) {
  contact.getContacts().then(function(contacts) {
    assert.equal(4,2)

    done()
  }).then(null, function (err) {
    console.error(err);

    done(err);
  });
})
```

Or instead of then(null, rejectFunc) use catch(rejectFunc) with libs like bluebird.

Also the answer by idbehold is great. I didn't know yet that mocha supports promises directly and I always use the done param knowing if I have a timeout without a stack trace there was a swallowed error in this test.

Comment: It is to handle the situations like "false positive". Isn't it @IIiyan ?

Comment: @muneermuhammed Yes, exactly.